# How to accept cookies only from my API server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch, session-cookies

I have a Expressjs API server on `localhost:4000`, and my client on `localhost:8008`.

How do I make it so that my client only accepts cookies that were set from my API server?

Currently, when I call an API with `fetch`, I specify the `credentials: 'include`, and it works. But I think I would want it to be `same-origin` right? Cos it's safer?

Comment: `localhost` has various quirks when it comes to safety, cross-origin things and the like. Optimizing for `localhost` probably is not worth the effort, you could rather fake some local domains via [`hosts`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))

Comment: Ya I shouldn't worry about this for now. Thanks @tevemadar

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for [cors](https://npmjs.org/package/cors). Here is a sample config :

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://yourhosthere.com/'
}));
```

However, you shouldn't test it on `localhost`, try modifying `hosts`.

Hope it helps!